# how do I configure a view to make two fields be inline

Tags: views

what format should I use in order to make two fields out of three be inline in a drupal 7 view, and how do I configure this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I decided to use display suite which makes it responsive as well.

Answer (score 5):

Hide the two fields in the views ui, then add a Global: Custom text field (make sure it is below the two hidden fields). In this field's text box you then add the two hidden fields back via replacement patterns (that's why it needs to be below the two hidden fields, else it will not see them), and wrap them in inline html or html that you will style inline.

You can use unformatted list format.

To make two rows out of three inline you will just use CSS with :nth selector. Else you can override the theme template for views (in advanced section). You copy and paste the template, then rename it to a proper suggestion. In that template it uses a loop to write the rows. You can rewrite that so that it loops over three at a time, prints two inline, one as block-level element.

Answer (score 4):

Under the Format section where it says 'Show: Fields | Settings' select settings. There is an inline fields section. Select the fields you want to be displayed inline.

**Note:** If the fields render as block elements simply change the CSS for the fields to `display: inline-block`.